# Liase between a few guest VMs and Windows host

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, bridge

I would like to combine a few VMs and Windows host machine by ssh (by rsa)

1. Network on VM -> Bridged
2. Guest: Ubuntu, Kali
3. Host: Windows

IP:

1. VM Kali IP -> 192.168.0.32 (static)
2. VM Ubuntu IP -> 192.168.0.31 (static)

sshd_config (the same settings on each VM):
Port 33555 (sudo systemctl status sshd -> ok)
PasswordAuthentication no

rsa keys + authorized_keys were generated/created on VM

Seems I missed something in my installation because even hosts (VM) are not pinged from both VMs:

```
ping 192.168.0.31 -> 100% packets loss
```

and expectedly connection by ssh fails as well:

```
 ssh -v -p33555 dev@192.168.0.31
```